# How does the wave model of light account for absorption?

Tags: optics, waves, absorption

I'm working on a blog post about wireless communication, and comparing the wave and particle models of light. I want to answer the same set of questions from the viewpoint of each model. One of these is "How is light absorbed?"

For the particle model, this is simple to answer (photons "knocking" electrons into higher energy states). But I can't find any material about the mechanism by which classical physicists thought light was absorbed. Everything I read on the topic always resorts to photons when they go into depth about absorption. So, I guess a succinct question might be:

**How did someone like Newton think light waves were absorbed by matter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton did not believe that light is due to waves, he pushed his particle theory of light.

Light waves are a later, more accomplished theory of light that overcame Newton's particles. It was developed by other people - Huyghens, Young, Fresnel and others.

After light waves were identified with EM waves by Maxwell and Hertz in 19th century, models of light-matter interaction that can describe light absorption were proposed. The simplest model is the Drude/Lorentz model, where the light wave makes charged particle oscillate while the particle is also being damped by a force of friction (damping force). Although not specified by that model, physically, the origin of this force is to be sought in mutual interaction of the oscillating particle with other nearby particles (damping due to environment).

As the oscillating particle is damped, its oscillations are out of phase with the excitating EM wave, so the EM wave produced by the oscillating particle counteracts the primary wave in the half space downstream. The resulting macroscopic EM wave manifests decay of amplitude with distance.

All this is subject of so-called linear response theory and theory of optical absorption/dispersion. For more on light matter interaction, you can look up these terms.

Answer (score 1):

Newton did not know what light was, did not know what matter was at all.

It was only with the discovery of electrons that people started to understand things a bit. The Drude model is still very good for explaining the optical conductivity of metals. Optical absorption is then related to the DC resistivity.

Many features of the optical properties of dielectrics can be understood with Lorentz oscillators: an elementary charge with a small mass bound to the nucleus and some damping.

Answer (score 0):

Just an answer to your primary question "How does the wave model of light account for absorption?"

Absorption is heat accumulation. the "object" that absorbs light gets hotter,... and/or emits light again.

But what is absorbed will result in higher kinetic energy of the atoms/particles that the object consists of = increased heat.

The heat or kinetic energy of the "particles" are vibrations: wavelets.

Same if one would consider the particles as wavelets, the wavelets get extra vibration energy.